# Sample in R throws too few positive probs

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

A problem with the sample function. With the attached data set I tried

after loading (column 9 is how often something occurs, and col 11 the associated var, the weight are in col eight

```
which(kfg[,9]==1)->aj
sample(kfg[aj,11],prob=kfg[aj,8])

Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  too few positive probabilities
```

This is confusing because

```
mean(kfg[aj,8])
#[1] 0.0009090909
```

Not all of the probabilities are the same value, could somebody maybe tell why this happens?

The dataset can be found here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gyimxbz5f3v0uq3/kfg.RData?dl=0

Answer (score 4):

You need one of `replace=TRUE` or `size` options since there are a bunch of 0 probabilities.  Otherwise, `sample` is trying to return the same number of elements as the length of the input, but can't do so because of a lack of positive probabilities.